# Python substitute column text

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

On execute the following line of code, I am getting **TypeError: repl must be a string or callable**

```
ps_df['Name'].str.replace(ps_df['Substitute'].str,'\n'+ps_df['Substitute'].str)
```

When I changed it to the following,

```
ps_df['Name'].str.replace(ps_df['Substitute'].str,'\n'+ps_df['Substitute'].str)
```

I get this error, **TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "StringMethods") to str**

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

According to pandas documentation for [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), the first argument should be a string or compiled regex.

But you are trying to feed in a series or a list of strings. Also, you have used the `.str` accessor of the series which is not properly used. Hence, the error.

You should be using apply to replace strings row-wise.

```
ps_df.apply(lambda x: x.Name.replace(x.Substitute, '\n' + x.Substitute), axis=1)
```